# Why i can't make a correlation matrix with larger number of values

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, correlation

I have a CSV file that looks something like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNn5b.png)

I make the correlation matrix with panda without problem but when the column values become a lot(more than 500), nothing happens the matrix is empty like everything deletes itself and I have no idea what is the problem

Comment: Can you maybe provide some code that you have already tried? By the way have checked if you have any empty cells in your dataframe?

Comment: There is nothing really special about my code it's just using pandas for the csv and making a correlation matrix with the values. I used a code for removing empty cells but perhaps it's not working properly can the empty values be the issue?

Comment: Yes that could create an issue. Run this code to see if you have any empty rows: df_name.isna().sum()

Comment: it looks like I have a couple that returned true for empty row.
dataframe = dataframe.replace('',np.nan)
dataframe = dataframe.dropna(axis="columns", how="any")
i use this code to remove it but its obviously not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this code?

```
# Import libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# In case you want correlation matrix for specific columns from df_full
df_regr2 = df_full[['var1', 'var2', 'var3']]
    

# Get correlations
df_corr2 = df_regr2.corr()

np.ones_like(df_corr2, dtype=np.bool)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))

ax.set_title('Title Name')

# Mask
mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(df_corr2, dtype=np.bool))

# Adjust mask and df
mask = mask[1:, :-1]
corr = df_corr2.iloc[1:,:-1].copy()

# Plot heatmap
sns.heatmap(corr, mask=mask, annot=True, fmt=".2f", cmap=plt.get_cmap('RdYlGn'),
           vmin=-1, vmax=1, cbar_kws={"shrink": .8})
# Yticks
plt.yticks(rotation=0)
plt.show()
```